# fb.login doesn't work in Chrome iOS

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using js sdk and I thought it was only happen to me, surprisingly this happened to many popular sites. Doubt why this issue still exist, and I tried many methods but no luck.

http://build.smartthings.com/login/

try to login with chrome ios, it return a blank page.